# Is there a "Apple Music App" for Windows10 OR is only the iTunes app available?

Tags: itunes, windows, music, apple-music

Is there a "Apple Music App" for Windows10 OR is only the iTunes app available?

On the Apple website, there is a link to download "iTunes For Windows"  but I am wondering if there is a separate  "Apple Music" app available or planned to be available?

Comment: There have been rumors of Apple Music for Android and/or windows, but so far only rumors. iTunes is it I do believe.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Apple Music app is only available for Macs at this time as your own research has indicated.  I don't think any user here can reasonably speak to any plans Apple has on Apple Music integration for Windows.  If they are an employee, they will be bound by nondisclosure; if they are not an employee, it will only be rumor at this point.  Your best answer for this kind of question will come from Apple's product support team.

Comment: Thanks. In that case, I'll use the web player.

Answer (score 0):

There is currently (5/2023) an [Apple Music Preview](https://apps.microsoft.com/store/detail/apple-music-preview/9PFHDD62MXS1) available from the Windows app store.

I assume it's a safe bet that a full version will be available soon.

[image: Screenshot of Windows app store showing Apple Music Preview]